# Access - Report opens and then is hidden when opening form is closed

Tags: ms-access, vba, reporting

I am using Access 2003 and I have a form that collects some filtering criteria for the report. Once the criteria is entered the user clicks and "OK" button and the report is launched using the following VBA.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview
```

After the report is opened I issue the following command to close the form that collected the filtering criteria ...

```
Me.Close
```

The form closes however the report, which I wanted to stay open in the foreground, is hidden. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Try replacing `Me.Close` with `DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name`. I don't recognize the former as being a valid VBA command in any version of Access I use on a daily basis. It's certainly not valid in A2003, unless you've created a custom subroutine/function in your form with that name.

Comment: Are you running this from the form or from the report? Also, what is me.Close? That shouldn't work.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - I tried your suggestion, and though the input form closes properly the report is sent "behind" the main switchboard form. I would like to keep the report in the foreground until the user closes it. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Does the Switchboard form have the popup property set to true? If not, you could try DoCmd.SelectObject to give the report the guaranteed focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all else fails with forms and reports coming to the front at the desired time, you can do it explicitly with DoCmd.SelectObject:

```
  DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMyReport", acViewPreview
  DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, "rptMyReport"
  DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```

If that doesn't work, there's something else involved, like forms or reports opened with the acDialog switch, or with forms/reports having the Modal or Popup properties set to True.

Or, there might be a timer running somewhere that's causing something to happen that's grabbing focus.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Report property Modal to Yes (in Other Properties).

Answer (score 0):

Does closing the form, then opening the report work?  I'm guessing it has to do with the focus being shifted back and forth between the objects.

EDIT

Your code should look something like this:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    'your code here

    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

    DoCmd.OpenReport "Report1", acViewPreview

End Sub
```

Also, there is no native close function as others have pointed out.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding what you meant. How could I go about closing the form but then opening the report? The input form is where the opening of the report is invoked.

Comment: There's something of a logic problem there and I'd hate to write code that works that way, i.e., closing the form where the code is running before the code stops running. I don't know what Access does in that case, but I'd rather not depend on it doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a couple days.  It seems you need to close the current window and then open the report in Print Preview.

I have a button on a pivotchart embedded in a Report. (Access2010)
When i tried to just print the report- any filtering on the pivot chart didn't get carried over to the "DoCmd.Printout" command.

It was suggested I use open the print preview window, but it never received focus. I had to click off screen then back toe the print preview window. The code below seems to correct this.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
DoCmd.Save
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenReport "R-MyReport", acViewPreview
```

Comment: Maybe take a second to look at the preview before you post your answer ;-)